# DB2 Logging Error

Tags: logging, db2

I have to migrate all Oracle scripts to DB2 Database .

Anyway i face that problem bellow :

```
 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO COOP(
                CCOOP,
                NDOCTO,
                ICOOP)
            VALUES (
                ps_iPkCooperativa ,
                v_xDocumentoCooperativa,
                v_xNomeCooperativa);
            COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                ROLLBACK;
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, (' GPRS6002 - ERRO: ' || SQLERRM || ' - ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE));
```

I dunno how i use **DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE** on DB2 database.

Someonome can help me out ?

Comment: IS the documentation for that routine in the Db2 knowledge center unclear for you ?

Comment: Yeap. 

Cause , if you see DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE its not able to use on DB2 database as far i know.

I try to use one called values DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE  , but unfortanelly i dunno have huge background on it , so actually i dont have idea how to do it.

Comment: Always post your Db2 version and server-platform when asking for Db2 help.  This routine is available in Db2 V11.1 on Linux/Unix/Windows.  The documentation is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0061937.html

Comment: ive already saw it . 

As i said , theres a sintaxy called **values dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace()** , i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Always post your Db2 version and server-platform when asking for Db2 help, because the answer depends on this information.

This routine is available in Db2 V11.1 and V10.5 (latest fixpack) on Linux/Unix/Windows. The documentation is  [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0061937.html).

If you are running Db2 V11.1 on LUW (or Version 10.5 at latest fixpack), and you follow the instructions for enabling Oracle compatibility mode *before* creating your database then both the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE routines are available and it is possible the Oracle scripts will run with minimal changes required. Sometimes no changes are needed, it depends on each script.

But this is only possible if you correctly follow instructions documented by IBM in the Db2 Knowledge Center.  If you have not configured Db2 LUW correctly for Oracle compatibility mode , this Oracle emulation is not available.

Comment: mao , im not get used to develop on DB2 database . Actually im using Data Studio Client to develop on it . As i saw here , i got DB2. v10.6

Comment: As far as I am aware, IBM has not released any product called Db2 v10.6 .  Do you mean Version 10.5 ?